# Apache Livy Security

Tags: linux, apache-spark, livy

We are trying to build a setup where we have a server that submits jobs of different users to the Livy server via the REST API. We established a  kerberos server to authenticate against livy. But we want to prohibit the users to access a different users' data, the filesystem, and the network.

My question would then be, how secure is livy? Users can inject custom code to run on livy, but this gives them the ability to access the filesystem on the host the livy server resides in. Even if we run livy with a different unix user, that has very little permissions on the filesystem, that could be potentially dangerous from my point of view, they could potentially access the keytab on the livy server also. And they could also potentially inject malware and run it.

I know that the session created creates also a JVM, so one session lives in a JVM, and it is impossible to see another session's data etc. without having the kerberos ticket, but could I change the security settings of that JVM to only access specific paths and specific IP addresses only? Would that mean for me to change the source code of livy?

And in the case of using HDFS with active directory to secure the datasystem, so that users need to specify a kerberos key to access their files, how could I manage multiple principals in one server, to get this working?

My conf file is as below:

```
livy.environment production
livy.impersonation.enabled true
livy.server.csrf_protection.enabled true
livy.server.port 8999
livy.server.session.timeout 3600000

livy.server.auth.kerberos.keytab /home/harun/Documents/incubator-livy/keytabs/new.keytab
livy.server.auth.kerberos.principal HTTP/livyserver.local@EXAMPLE.COM
livy.server.auth.type kerberos
#livy.server.launch.kerberos.keytab /home/harun/Documents/incubator-livy/conf/livy.headless.keytab
#livy.server.launch.kerberos.principal livy@EXAMPLE.COM
livy.server.access_control.enabled = true
livy.server.access_control.users = livy
livy.superusers=livy
```

PS: Does enabling launch.kerberos provide additional security to protect the keytab?

Any help to any of the questions is very much appriciated,

Thanks in forehand